# Value Error with input_length and shape in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

So, I am trying to build a text generator using Keras. I have 35983 sentences of length 50 i.e. my training data x has a shape of `(35983,50,1)`. However, I cannot figure out how to give the input shape to my model ad keep running into errors. The other dimensions in my model are:

```
Embedding Matrix: (46, 45)
vocab_size = 45
```

Here is the structure of my model:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(TimeDistributed(Embedding(vocab_size + 1, vocab_size, input_length= 50, weights = [embedding_weights], input_shape = (x.shape[1],x.shape[2]))))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv1D(64, 3, activation = 'relu', kernel_initializer= 'glorot_normal')))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling1D(pool_size= 2)))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv1D(64, 3, activation = 'relu', kernel_initializer = 'glorot_normal')))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling1D(pool_size= 2)))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv1D(64, 3, activation = 'relu', kernel_initializer = 'glorot_normal')))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling1D(pool_size= 2)))
model.add(TimeDistributed(GlobalMaxPool1D()))
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(256, return_sequences = True)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(256, return_sequences = True)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(y.shape[1], activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss = 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer = 'rmsprop', metrics = ['accuracy'])
model.build((None, x.shape[1],x.shape[2]))
model.summary()
```

Everytime I try to run the above code I get the following error:

```
ValueError: "input_length" is 50, but received input has shape (None, 1)
```

I have tried chopping and changing the shapes but I still get a similar error and I can't figure out how to get rid of it. Any help would be appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: Could you print the shape of `x`?

Comment: Ah sorry, i should've specified that x is (35983,50,1)

Comment: Are you sure?? According to this error, it's not that

Comment: I am sure. Maybe I have done something wrong in model.build() or in the embedding layer? Cause the error seems to point to model.build() but I cannot figure out what change I should make

Comment: then, hard-code it... try `model.build((None, 50, 1))`

Comment: The same error gets raised even when I do that. If I try model.build((None,1,50)) then it compiles but when I try and fit the model I get the following error: ```ValueError: Error when checking input: expected sequential_41_input to have shape (1, 50) but got array with shape (50, 1)```

Answer (score 0):

May this will help you.

```
I = Input(shape=(50, 50)) # each search result is made of 50 words and 50 docs

emb = Embedding(
    max_val,
    embedding_dims,
    dropout=embedding_dropout
)


right = TimeDistributed(emb)(I)
right = TimeDistributed(Convolution1D(nb_filter=5,
                        filter_length=5,
                        border_mode='valid',
                        activation='relu',
                        subsample_length=1)(right)
right = TimeDistributed(GlobalMaxPooling1D())(right)
```